# Trouble in looping while printing a series

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have to write a program in C++ that will print a sequence of 10 numbers based on user supplied variable input.

Expected output:

> Input a number: 10
>
> Series: 11 13 16 20 25 31 38 46 55 65

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    int j, sum = 0, b=1; 
    for (j = 10; j <= 65; j=j+b++) 
    { 
        sum = sum + j;
        printf("%d\n",j);
    } 
}
```

I've hardcoded it with respect to the given sample. How can I make it work for variable inputs?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why does the series start with 11? What is the rule for the next number?

Comment: @FlatAssembler +1, +2, +3, +4, +5 ... pretty basic puzzle!

Comment: @FlatAssembler I think it starts from `input + 1`

Comment: it add a 10 to 1 that's why 11 then add 2 that's why 13

Comment: @ArdentCoder actually it's `input + 1` with geometric progression ;)

Comment: @metablaster No it isn't. A geometric progression would involve multiplication.

Comment: I meant arithmetic progression, my bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: @metablaster It's not an arithmetic progression either. From your link: _"the difference between the consecutive terms is constant"_.

Comment: @FlatAssembler yes it just simple addition, i tried something but the output is 11, 12 ..20

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int  j, sum = 0, b=1;

    for (j = 10; j <= 65; j=j+b++)
    {
        sum = sum + j;
        printf("%d\n",j);    
    }
}

Comment: You apply arithmetic progression only to `i` not entry `input + i` and that' arithmetic increase of value `i`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is almost complete, your part of job is to update one line where comment says `/* ??? */`

See code comments for more info:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Starting value, ex. 10, chosen by user
    int input = 0;

    // Length of the sequence, also chosen by user
    int length = 0;

    // Sequence is incremented according to the pattern you already know
    // for more info see:
    // https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html
    int adder = 0;

    // Ask user to input starting number
    std::cout << "Please enter the starting number: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    // TODO: verify user input is number

    // Ask user for desired length of a sequence
    std::cout << "Please enter the desired length of sequence: ";
    std::cin >> length;

    std::cout << "Generating sequence..." << std::endl;

    // Generate sequence
    // TODO: your part of job is to replace the ???
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; ++counter, input += /* ??? */)
    {
        // Show the current number in the sequence
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some suggestions: `adder` is an unused variable, `length` is always equal to 10 (from the question).

Comment: @ArdentCoder haha, I see you share the style of writing code with me, how cool! :) as for sequence length, I don't see a problem here, in other answer there is a comment that it should be included. and the `adder` variable is what should be put into `/* ??? */`

Comment: Nice. Btw that comment was put before making drastic edits to the question, anyways `length` makes your code more flexible and OP can `const` it to 10 if they want. And I thought `counter` was the answer to your puzzle :P

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    int lastNumber=n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        lastNumber+=i;
        cout <<lastNumber <<' ';
    }
    endl(cout);
}
```

Comment: Also I suspect the sequence length _10_ was intended to be fixed, not taken from the input, though I concede that was left unspecified.